# Access protected Java attribute from Jython

Tags: java, swing, jython

I am building a text editor with Jython using Java Swing. I have come across [CompoundEdit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/CompoundEdit.html), a Swing class that has a list of edit actions from a text editor. This attribute is protected, which means that I can't access it directly from another class, but I can from other classes that extend it. So, if I create a `MyEdit` class that extends `CompoundEdit`, `MyEdit` should have access to the list of edits.

This is what I'm trying:

```
class MyEdit(CompoundEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CompoundEdit, self).__init__()
        print(dir(self)) # Doesn't show the edits
        self.nammu_edits = super(CompoundEdit, self).edits
```

Running this gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'edits'
```

For reference, this is what `dir` comes back with:

```
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__ensure_finalizer__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__initProxy__', '__init__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__supernames__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', '_getPyInstance', '_getPySystemState', '_setPyInstance', '_setPySystemState', 'addEdit', 'canRedo', 'canUndo', 'class', 'classDictInit', 'clone', 'die', 'doPrint', 'end', 'equals', 'finalize', 'getClass', 'getPresentationName', 'getRedoPresentationName', 'getUndoPresentationName', 'hashCode', 'inProgress', 'isInProgress', 'isSignificant', 'lastEdit', 'notify', 'notifyAll', 'presentationName', 'redo', 'redoPresentationName', 'replaceEdit', 'significant', 'toString', 'undo', 'undoPresentationName', 'wait']
```

And this is an extract of the CompoundEdit.java code:

```
public class CompoundEdit extends AbstractUndoableEdit {
    /**
     * True if this edit has never received <code>end.
     */
    boolean inProgress;

    /**
     * The collection of <code>UndoableEdits
     * undone/redone en masse by this <code>CompoundEdit.
     */
    protected Vector<UndoableEdit> edits;

    public CompoundEdit() {
        super();
        inProgress = true;
        edits = new Vector<UndoableEdit>();
    }
```

I have tried the exact same from Java, and it lets me access `edits`. Is there something I'm doing wrong in the Jython version? Is there a special way in Jython to access protected variables? In the documentation it mentions something about calling `super__<method>()`, but I tried it for this case and it also doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to set `python.security.respectJavaAccessibility = false`? See http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/appendixA.html#python-security-respectjavaaccessibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mzjn is correct. Setting `python.security.respectJavaAccessibility = false` is the only way to access a protected field from a subclass. This is due to this piece of code in `org.python.core.PyJavaType.init(Class<?>, Set<PyJavaType>)`:

```
// Add fields declared on this type
Field[] fields;
if (Options.respectJavaAccessibility) {
    // returns just the public fields
    fields = forClass.getFields();
} else {
    fields = forClass.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
    }
}
```

However, you *can* call protected methods without setting `respectJavaAccessibility` to `false`, as method lookup uses a different algorithm. IMO this is a bug, I was not able to find any mentions that this behavior is intended.

Or just use Java reflection to get the protected field value:

```
class MyEdit(CompoundEdit):
    #...
    def get_edits(self):
        edits_field = CompoundEdit.getDeclaredField('edits')
        edits_field.setAccessible(True)
        return edits_field.get(self)
```